# Scheduling job to start 9.00 am and then every 15 minutes in autosys

Tags: autosys

I'm new to autosys.
I wanted to plan a work that starts at 9.00 and runs every 15 minutes. Is this the proper syntax?

```
start.times=start_times: "09:00"
start_mins:00,15,30,45
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a run window.
A run window cannot wrap around midnight or whatever time you start your new day processing. The default is midnight
If you want a start time for a job to run every 15 minutes then use this

start_mins: 00,15,30,45

run_window: "09:00-22:00"

22:00 can be whatever you want or as far as 23:59 if your new day processing starts at midnight.